# 500 error code bug when trying to delete Google+ account

Tags: google-plus, google-account, account-management

It is February 2, 2019. When trying to delete my Google+ account, I encounter a 500 error code bug. My account will not delete. How do I delete my account?

Comment: Don't worry, in April 2019, Google+ will be shut down anyway. So, you just have to wait a few weeks... Too bad that they have decided to close it!...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google+ has been retired.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google+ has been retired.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 indicates that something went wrong on Google's side which means your options are:

- try again
- wait and try again later

---

**[what is error 500?](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error)**